# Library - google.cloud: Object has no attribute 'schema_from_json'

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the "schema_from_json" attribute from the google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client library but it does not find this attribute and in the library documentation it appears.

I already updated the library but it remains the same.

My Python version is 3.7

Source: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
dir(bigquery.client.Client)
['SCOPE',
 '_SET_PROJECT',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getstate__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_call_api',
 '_determine_default',
 '_do_multipart_upload',
 '_do_resumable_upload',
 '_get_query_results',
 '_http',
 '_initiate_resumable_upload',
 'cancel_job',
 'copy_table',
 'create_dataset',
 'create_table',
 'dataset',
 'delete_dataset',
 'delete_table',
 'extract_table',
 'from_service_account_json',
 'get_dataset',
 'get_job',
 'get_service_account_email',
 'get_table',
 'insert_rows',
 'insert_rows_json',
 'job_from_resource',
 'list_datasets',
 'list_jobs',
 'list_partitions',
 'list_projects',
 'list_rows',
 'list_tables',
 'load_table_from_dataframe',
 'load_table_from_file',
 'load_table_from_uri',
 'location',
 'query',
 'update_dataset',
 'update_table']
```

Comment: What do you want to do? autodetect the json schema when performing a load job?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I want to get a schema json file that is in the cloud storage and that it is a reference for the ingestion of my data inside bigquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested from cloud shell and it works.

here the pip dependency of cloud shell:`google-cloud-bigquery          1.18.0`

here my working code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'us_dataset'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
# I use from file path version
schema_dict = client.schema_from_json("schemaname")
print(schema_dict)
job_config.schema = schema_dict
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
job_config.create_disposition = bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED

# The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
uri = "gs://MY_BUCKET/name.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, dataset_ref.table("name"), job_config=job_config
)  # API request
print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
print("Job finished.")

destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table("name"))
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

I generate schema file with this command: `bq show --schema us_dataset.name > schemaname`

And here the result

```
[{"type":"STRING","name":"name","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"STRING","name":"id","mode":"NULLABLE"}]
```

Comment: You can send me a following command response: dir(bigquery.Client)

Comment: `['SCOPE', '_SET_PROJECT', '__class__', ................, 'query', 'schema_from_json', 'schema_to_json', 'update_dataset', 'update_model', 
'update_routine', 'update_table']` I have the method `schema_from_json`.